# RestClientException client shows empty response body for Spring Client authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am using Spring Oauth client setup on my frontend. I'm authentication against my API, which returns this

```
 {
   error: "unauthorized"
   error_description: "User does not exist"
 }
```

using my rest client (Google Plug: Advance RestClient); which is expected.When I use Spring Oauth Client setup, I was expecting that the error object `RestClientException` would have that JSON result in the response body however it is empty. See attached image (Watch Console shows what's in the response body).

[image]

***Right click the image and select `open image in new tab` to make the image bigger***

#### Request sent

grant_type=c_password&username=test&password=test&client_id=test&client_secret=test

#### Response

```
 Date: Sun, 26 Apr 2015 20:59:45 GMT 
 Connection: close
 Cache-Control: no-store 
 Pragma: no-cache 
 Www-Authenticate: Bearer realm="api/", error="unauthorized",  error_description="User does not exist"
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
 Server: Jetty(7.x.y-SNAPSHOT) 
 Via: 1.1 vegur 
 Raw
 JSON
```

Comment: Which Spring version are you using? Could you paste here the request and response HTTP headers?

Comment: @BrianClozel the request is being made using Spring Oauth (client side). The setup is a client to API request. The API is secured using Spring Oauth as well. The client website is using: Spring Security 3.2.3.RELEASE, Spring 3.2.8.RELEASE and Spring Oauth 2.0.4.RELEASE. On the API, I'm using: Spring 4.0.8.RELEASE, Spring Security 3.2.5.RELEASE and 1.0.5.RELEASE. I made an bug issue with Spring Oauth (which isn't related to that library) https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/441

Comment: Again - could you copy/paste HTTP request and response headers?

Comment: @BrianClozel see the first post for the request and response headers.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a `RestTemplate` bug - your server (or the proxy) is using a combination of `Connection: close` and no `Content-Length` headers.

One way to confirm this: make your server write Content-Length headers (in Spring, adding a [ShallowEtagHeaderFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-etag) will do that).

If this workaround fixes this, then this bug has been fixed in [SPR-8016](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8016) - upgrading the client application to Spring 4.1.5 will solve this.

Answer (score 0):

it seems the actual exception that you are getting is not RestClientException. Just debug the error, it would be something HttpClientErrorException. So catch this exception instead of above one. This exception has methods to get the desired result.